# Formalities calling work colleagues, clients an partners as Pal/Pals

Tags: word-choice, expressions, formality

In my work we have a collaborative tool for work interaction where we debate things like workflow and issues. I'm in a interaction with workmates, client employees and partners. I thought to reference to all participants as pals. Ex.:

> Pals,
>
> We need some resources to complete this task...

Could it seems disrespectful or inappropriate? If yes, Can I use `To all` as an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pal is a buddy or friend, or worse, a [sarcastic way to indicate your annoyance with someone](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pal). It's possible that some of your client employees and partners haven't met. And you don't want to give this large group the impression that you are annoyed with anyone. Probably best to go with your alternative, "To All".

Answer (score 1):

***Hello, Everyone***

might be a good start. "Pals" and "Fellows" don't ring quite right in a business environment.